# Ubuntu server X display

Tags: server, virtualbox, qt

I am new in Ubuntu. 
I've installed Ubuntu server 18.04 (cli version, no GUI) and virtualbox software on it. 
Now I am trying to run virtualbox but I am getting the following errors. I am sure I need to install some additional packages (e.g X windows ) but I don't what exactly I need. 
Please help me.

I connected to server over SSH console:

```
root@oovm:/etc/apt# vboxmanage --version
5.2.18_Ubuntur123745

root@oovm:/etc/apt# virtualbox
Qt WARNING: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Qt WARNING: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Qt CRITICAL: Could not connect to any X display.
```

Please give me an instruction how to make everything work.

Thank you.
Regards

Comment: A GUI is needed for Virtualbox. Considering you probably don't have any valid reason to be using the server edition, go ahead and install the regular desktop edition.

Comment: Server already installed. And I need to forward graphics over SSH to my windows host

Comment: The CLI client is called VBoxManage: see for example [Controlling VirtualBox from the Command Line](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/manage-vbox-cli-2264359.html)

Comment: ... FWIW the most likely reason the `virtualbox` (GUI) command is failing is that you either aren't running an X server on the Windows host, or haven't forwarded X over your SSH connection to it.

Comment: So you have a windows host, how xsession is handled on there? Do you have cygwin or how you run xsession over ssh between different os?